# Spring Boot moving from war to jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-failsafe-plugin

I tried to move from war to jar using Spring Boot 2.0.2 and I encountered issues with my maven tests using failsafe.

I see two kinds of errors:

1. `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest`
2. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with one of my bean class listed

When I run those tests in IntelliJ everything works fine, but they fail in maven.
At the same time when I go back to building war instead of jar, everything works also.

By moving from war to jar I mean adding a `repackage` goal to spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${spring.boot.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And removing `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` from my class that has the main method, and moving the `configure` method into the `main` method:

```
@Import(JpaAuditingHandlerRegistrar.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
@Lazy
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class))
        .run(args);
}


private static SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    String env = System.getenv("ENV");
    if (env != null) {
        if (Collections.disjoint(List.of(PRODUCTION), List.of(pulsarEnv))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Unknown ENV provided: %s", env)
            );
        }
        application.profiles(
            env,
            Profiles.METRICS
        );
    }
    return application;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class))
        .run(args);
}
```

My test classes are annotated with:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class,
    ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    MockitoTestExecutionListener.class
})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(TestConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

Another puzzler, when I run the tests using

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test
```

They all work, so they fail only in case of `mvn clean install`, why?

Comment: If it's the JUnit that is failing do you have the @SpringBootTest on it?  I don't see your JUnit code.

Comment: 1) The repackage  goal is enabled by default. Why adding it ? Why adding Spring loaded with the WAR change ? 2) How the main class may compile ? You specified `@Override` in the `configure()` method but your class extends `Object` ! Please try to be clearer and more exact if you want to get relevant pointers/answers.

Comment: Yes, all SpringBootTests are failing. Not sure how is war and jar different for spring boot. And why they work in IDE and not in maven.

Comment: @davidxxx I copied from the war case, updated now

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the issue is that I'm using failsafe 2.19.1, and this version has issues since Spring boot 1.4.x: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254

Solution is to either downgrade failsafe to 2.18, upgrade it (but then another set of issues appear) or add

```
<classifier>exec</classifier>
```

To the configuration part of spring-boot-maven-plugin, in my case it will be:
            
                org.springframework.boot
                spring-boot-maven-plugin
                
                    ${spring.boot.skip}
                    exec
                
                
                    
                        
                            build-info
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        org.springframework
                        springloaded
                        1.2.6.RELEASE